# Kingswaysoft Error Connecting to CRM On Premise

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I have an SSIS package that updates a custom entity in CRM (On-Premise - 8.2). The package uses the Kingswaysoft WebAPI method to connect to CRM. When I deploy and try executing it from the server it gives the following error. I am not able to get past it. Can you help me here?

> An error has occurred when trying to write connection metering information to the system.  (Component name: CrmDestinationComponent; Machine/Instance name: Server Name, License Key: Kingswaysoft License Key in the server)

Comment: Is there any further details that can be found in the logs of the CRM?  It's smelling a little like a write permission issue, but that's purely a guess.

Comment: This would be a permission issue. You should have better luck if you are on a newer version. It is believed that this case is currently handled by our client services team.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have the latest and correct version installed on server. From the change log, this issue was fixed in one of the version (v 10.2)

> [All] Fixed: Our software may report a connection metering related error during runtime for some specific system environments.

[Reference](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/change-log)

You may get assistance from official KWS account in SO here, otherwise create a support ticket with them.